# How to get a user from an IGraphServiceClient object?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a **POST method** and want to get a user from an **IGraphServiceClient** object (in the **Graph.Microsoft** package and namespace).
The GET method works fine. Then I take a user from this list and set them as a parameter for my POST method.

```
    public async Task<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> GetUserGroupsAsync(ICollection<string> userIds)
    {
        var aggregatedUserGroupMap = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        foreach (string userId in userIds)
        {
            try
            {
                var userMemberOfCollectionRequest = graphServiceClient.Users[userId].MemberOf.Request();
                var userMemberOfCollection = await userMemberOfCollectionRequest.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (!aggregatedUserGroupMap.ContainsKey(userId)) { aggregatedUserGroupMap.Add(userId, new List<string>()); }
                foreach (var memberOf in userMemberOfCollection) { aggregatedUserGroupMap[userId].Add(memberOf.Id); }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return aggregatedUserGroupMap;
    }
```

The values in the incoming string collection, `userIds`, are user email addresses, copied from the GET result.

The value of `userMemberOfCollectionRequest` looks fine. The `RequestUrl` property contains "https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users/my-email@compagny.com/memberOf". `Headers` and `QueryOptions` are empty collections.

In the above method, the following line throws an exception:

```
var userMemberOfCollection = await userMemberOfCollectionRequest.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The exception message reads:

> Request_ResourceNotFound
>
> Resource 'my-email@compagny.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
>
> at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
>      at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
>      at Microsoft.Graph.UserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesRequest.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at xxx.xxx.BusinessComponent.GraphBC.GetUserGroupsAsync(ICollection`1 userIds) in C:\workspace\xxx\xxx.xxx\xxx.xxx.Core\BusinessComponent\GraphBC.cs:line 50

**Does anyone have an idea for where I should look to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

The solution was not to use the email, instead using the `ObjectId` property (a GUID instead of an email).